Docker laravel and vue not working: Vue is not been recognised
I have docker container with Laravel 11 I have installed the vue dependencies as per the instructions on the official documentation. Issue am having is that my vue components are not loading in. I bash into the laravel container I run npm install and npm run dev it loads successfully. when i click on the  http://localhost:5173 I get error on page like it doesn't work.
VITE v5.4.7  ready in 5458 ms
➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  press h + enter to show help
LARAVEL v11.23.5  plugin v1.0.5
➜  APP_URL: http://localhost:9000
Here are my config files. Not sure what am doing wrong
Vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});


Package JS
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  laravel-docker:
    container_name: laravel-docker
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./realtime:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:80  # Keeping 9000 for Laravel app
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rttm_db
    volumes:
      - "./db:/var/lib/mysql"  # Persist database data
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mysql_db
    networks:
      - app-network

  npm:
    image: node:current-alpine
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./realtime:/var/www/html
    user: node
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["npm", "install"]  # Install dependencies (or run other npm commands)
    networks:
      - app-network

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - app-network
            
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Mod Rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev 

# Install PHP Zip extension
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
# Install Redis    
RUN pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis
# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# PHP Extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext intl pdo_mysql gd

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
# install curl 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest

I was expect vue components to display correctly

Can you give us the dockerfile ?

I have added the dockerfile

" I get error on page like it doesn't work." - which error?

localhost:5173 url to check if vue is working shows can not be reached. Then app.js and css file in the inspector for the laravel page have errors that it can not be reached

You need to open development port 5173 for npm container.
npm:
    image: node:current-alpine
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./realtime:/var/www/html
    user: node
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["npm", "install"]  # Install dependencies (or run other npm commands)
    ports:
          - 5173:5173
    networks:
      - app-network

